# Pyspark Spark DataFrame - Aggregate and filter columns in map type column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, aggregate-functions

My `DataFrame` looks like:

```
| c1 | c2|  c3  |
|----+---+-------
| A  | b | 22:00| 
| A  | b | 23:00|
| A  | b | 09:00|
| A  | c | 22:00|
| B  | c | 09:30|
```

I would like to perform some aggregations and create a second `DataFrame` with 3 columns:

**c1**:  is the column that I want to group by.

**map_category_room_date**: map type, key the `c2` and value the lower/min value in `c3`.

**cnt_orig**: is the count on how many rows the original group had.

***Result***

```
|    c1    |  map_category_room_date | cnt_orig |
|----------+-------------------------+----------|
|   'A'    |{'b': 09:00, 'C': 22:00} |    4     |
|   'B'    |{'c': 09:30}             |    1     |
```

What aggregate functions can I use to archive this is the most simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can `window` function to generate the `count`, then use `inbuilt functions` to get the final dataframe you desire by doing to following

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("c1")

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("cnt_orig", count('c1').over(windowSpec)).orderBy('c3').groupBy("c1", "c2", "cnt_orig").agg(first('c3').as('c3'))
    .withColumn("c2", F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.array($"c2", $"c3").cast(StringType), "[\\[\\]]", ""), ",", " : "))
      .groupBy("c1", "cnt_orig").agg(F.collect_list("c2").as('map_category_room_date'))
```

You should get the following result

```
+---+--------+----------------------+
|c1 |cnt_orig|map_category_room_date|
+---+--------+----------------------+
|A  |4       |[b : 09:00, c : 22:00]|
|b  |1       |[c : 09:00]           |
+---+--------+----------------------+
```

**Scala way**

working code to get the desired output in scala is

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("c1")

df.withColumn("cnt_orig", count("c1").over(windowSpec)).orderBy("c3").groupBy("c1", "c2", "cnt_orig").agg(first("c3").as("c3"))
    .withColumn("c2", regexp_replace(regexp_replace(array($"c2", $"c3").cast(StringType), "[\\[\\]]", ""), ",", " : "))
      .groupBy("c1", "cnt_orig").agg(collect_list("c2").as("map_category_room_date"))
```

Comment: Didn't my answer helped you @Lou_Ds?

Comment: It seems to have _invalid syntax_. But thanks for the post. :)

Comment: invalid syntax? what is that?

Comment: Did you test the snippet you posted? I might be missing something but I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax. In the "python version".

Comment: I tested in scala and coverted the scala code to pyspark. :) which line are you getting invalid syntax?

Comment: I think it might be different in python. can you try to run your snipped?  `.. F.regexp_replace(array('c2','c3').cast(StringType) ..` is giving me a `TypeError`

Comment: oh I got that :) it should be F.array . let me correct the answer

Comment: Yes, like `count` and `first` also need F.. Other parts are also scala syntax (like `($"c2",`), but converting what I know, still was not able to get it running :/

Comment: Hi...how to access the elements of a map say if I only want to get the value of b or c map_category_room_date