# How to transpose Columns to Rows in a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, transpose

I have this DF for example

```
+----+------+------+-------+
| id | val1 | val2 | val3  |
+----+------+------+-------+
|  1 |   a  |   b  |   c   |
|  2 |   d  |   e  |   f   |
|  3 |   g  |   h  |   i   |
```

and I want the Columns `val1`, `val2` and `val3` transposed into Rows in this way:

```
+----+------+------+
| id |  key | value|
+----+------+------+
|  1 | val1 |   a  |
|  1 | val2 |   b  |
|  1 | val3 |   c  |
|  2 | val1 |   d  |
|  2 | val2 |   e  |
|  2 | val3 |   f  |
|  3 | val1 |   g  |
|  3 | val2 |   h  |
|  3 | val3 |   i  |
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

By exploding a Map structure it is possible to get such transformation. So first transform the 3 columns into a Map (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291156/4725074) for then exploding.

So given the following Spark DF:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from itertools import chain


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()

d = [
    {'id': 1, 'val1': 'a', 'val2': 'b', 'val3': 'c'},
    {'id': 2, 'val1': 'd', 'val2': 'e', 'val3': 'f'},
    {'id': 3, 'val1': 'g', 'val2': 'h', 'val3': 'i'},
     ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)
```

the solution would be:

```
m = F.create_map(list(chain(*(
        (F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in df.columns if c in ["val1", "val2", "val3"]))))

df.withColumn('map', m)\
  .select('*', F.explode('map')).drop('map')
```

It's important to use a `select()` and not a `witchColumn()` as when exploding a Map column will generate 2 new columns, `key` and `value`.

The result will be the transposition of the selected columns into rows as reported in the example.

Comment: I am trying to use above logic for my dataframe which has about 300 columns and I am passing a list I want here ["val1", "val2", "val3"], but above code doesnot give transpose my columns to rows, it ias as is

Comment: it might be that 300 columns is a big number and this is an expensive operations... try with just a small sample and check if that works