# Rewrite Pyspark function to join columns in json

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I need to get all columns of a Spark Datadrame and create other column as a json having keys and values as column names and values. For example, a Dataframe like this:

| C1 | C2 | CN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | abc |
| 99 |  | cde |
| 40 | 50 |  |

Should be transformed to this:

| C1 | C2 | CN | JSON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | abc | { "C1": 10, "C2": 20, "CN": "abc"} |
| 30 |  | def | { "C1": 99, "CN": "cde"} |
| 40 | 50 |  | { "C1": 99, C2: 50} |

The columns names and number may vary, so I can't pass it explicitly.
The strategy I'm using is:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def jsonize_fields(row):
    vars = {}
    for k, v in row.asDict().items():
        if v:
            vars[k] = v
    return json.dumps(vars)

jsonize_udf = udf(jsonize_fields, StringType())
spark_data_frame = spark_data_frame.withColumn('JSON',
jsonize_udf(struct(*spark_data_frame.columns)))
```

This works well, but it degraded the performance a lot. So, I would like to convert it to a solution that doesn't use UDF. Is it possible?

Comment: does this help? -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288622/pyspark-create-maptype-column-from-existing-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json

spark_data_frame = spark_data_frame.withColumn('JSON',
    to_json(struct(*spark_data_frame.columns)))
```

By default, `to_json` ignore null values (it can be changed by using as second parameter `options={"ignoreNullFields": False})`), but not empty ones.
If you want to ignore empty values also, put it before:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when

spark_data_frame = spark_data_frame.select(
    [when(col(c)=="",None).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) for c in spark_data_frame.columns])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a straightforward way to achieve this without using UDFs.

However, PySpark actually has a built-in [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html) function for turning a `STRUCT` into a JSON string. You don't need to write your own.

Behind the scenes, `to_json` will call Spark's internal implementation of the function. In turn, that removes the overhead associated with Python UDFs and should improve performance.

The usage is very similar to your custom UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, to_json

spark_data_frame = spark_data_frame.withColumn(
    'JSON',
    to_json(struct(*spark_data_frame.columns))
)
```